# How can I install/import pyspark-csv?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I'm trying to use data from CSV files in PySpark. I found a module called PySpark-CSV which does exactly what I need. According to the [PySpark-CSV GitHub page](https://github.com/seahboonsiew/pyspark-csv), "no installation [is] required", so I figured I could just unzip the source in a directory called 'pyspark_csv' in my Python path and run the commands listed on their website:

```
import pyspark_csv as pycsv
sc.addPyFile('pyspark_csv.py')
```

But this renders me with an import error saying that it can't find pyspark_csv.

The README doesn't help me any further and other info is scarce. Anyone here familiar with the module?

Comment: keep the `.py` file in your PYTHONPATH

Comment: do you sure that name of module you placed in your `Python` folder and name you try to import within your code are exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means Python cannot find `pyspark_csv.py`. This is because you put the file in `pyspark_csv` and Python unaware that. Let say a full path of the directory is `/foo/pyspark_csv'. You can modify PYTHONPATH, or use other methods to inform Python where have you put your files.

```
#Run this in bash shell before you excute python
#Or put thisline in a bottom of .bashrc file.
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/foo/pyspark_csv
```

Use a full path for Spark, too:

```
sc.addPyFile('/foo/pyspark_csv/pyspark_csv.py')
```